# Residual Stress Induced By Shot Peening

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, finite-element-method

I'm interested in the residual stress profile induced by shot peening. Most of the papers I have read do some measurement and include a graphic which looks like: [image]

This graphic identifies how the residual stress varies with depth. Presumably, if the depth direction is Z and the shot peening balls strike a surface parallel to the X-Y plane then this graphic illustrates the residual stress in the directions X and Y. Is it correct to assume that the stresses are symmetric in the X and Y directions? Also, would shot peening have any impact on the component of stress in the Z direction, the direction of depth? Is it assumed that the component of stress in the Z direction is negligible compared to the components in the X and Y directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stress component in $Z$ direction $\sigma_z$ must be in equilibrium with normal pressure at the surface. If there is no pressure, $\sigma_z$ is zero (it can still be nonzero below the surface). However, this component is important during the peening, because during the impact, this component is definitely nonzero at the surface and the compression must be so intensive, that it induces some plastic deformation. After that, $\sigma_z$ drops to zero at the surface.

Assuming shot peening is done perpendicularly to the surface, symmetry in $X-Y$ could depend on the shape and size of specimen. The symmetry would probably be worst for small specimens of irregular shapes.